# How to add Accordion to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have 3 JPanels and these 3 are in a JPanel as well. I am trying to show or hide these 3 JPanels when I click a button or something like TitledPane(I am not sure what is the difference between an Accordion and TitledPane) sample below:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/img/accordion-sample1.png

But I noticed that I can not just add TitledPane or Accordion to a JPanel with panel.add(accordion) or panel.add(titledPanel). (Assume that panel is a JPanel)
How can I do that?

Comment: You really shouldn't mix Swing and JavaFX unless you really have to. Is there a reason you are mixing the two different UI toolkits?

Comment: Mixing Swing and JavaFX doesn't seem like a great idea

Comment: @James_D Are there anything similar with TitledPane in Swing? I really need something to show / hide panels like TitledPane. I mean when one panel is hiden then the panel that is below of it must move to up.

Comment: Not that I know of; though it is years since I used Swing.

Comment: You can put JavaFX nodes in a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html); note however you are entering a world of pain and will need to know how to write multithreaded code, as your FX controls can only be accessed from the FX Application Thread, and your Swing components can only be accessed from the AWT event dispatch thread. I would not recommend this for novice or intermediate programmers.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the answer, so there is no easy way to show / hide panels like how TitledPane does in Swing. :( I will look for another idea.

Comment: If you don't have too much Swing code yet, I would rewrite the whole thing in JavaFX

Comment: @Dici Actually it is my "Computer Project" which is a necessary things to do like "Graduation Project" in my university and I almost finished it. So can't go back. Thanks

Comment: I wrote this https://github.com/javagl/CommonUI/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/common/ui/panel/collapsible/CollapsiblePanel.java a while ago (with a small example here https://github.com/javagl/CommonUI/blob/master/src/test/java/de/javagl/common/ui/panel/collapsible/test/CollapsiblePanelTest.java ). It should be fairly standalone, and you can just copy the single class and use it, if it suits your needs.

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks a lot. I actually changed my mind, I am not gonna use an accordion but I will take a look at your code. Thanks again for sharing it with me.